# PhpStorm PHPUnit testreporter error

Tags: phpunit, php, phpstorm

I have installed PHPUnit via Composer and set it up to run the unit tests with my installation through settings.

But when I run the tests I get the following error for the test reporter (the tets executes just fine):

> Unable to attach test reporter to test framework or test framework quit unexpectedly

Comment: This means: PHP cannot find some of the files required for execution (could be PHPUnit own files .. or your actual tests). **1)** Check your PHP error log for possible details; **2)** Show your PHPUnit configuration (the Run/Debug Configuration as well as from "Settings | PHP | PHPUnit")

Comment: In any case: please have a look at this article: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PHPUnit+Installation+via+Composer+in+PhpStorm

Comment: @Blacksonic Please give feedback hów this turned out for you.

Comment: ill try it out today ;)

Comment: i pointed the loader to the bin directory of composer, that might be the problem...so it can run it but couldnt find the files without autoload.php...will check if this is the cause of failure

Comment: *"i pointed the loader to the bin directory of composer"* -- WRONG -- you should point it to your `vendor/autoload.php` (that blog post mentioned earlier has it in pictures -- to help avoid such confusions). Same mistake as here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-18362 . If that is actually your case -- consider voting/commenting this ticket: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-18388

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You should point to your `vendor/autoload.php` at `Settings | PHP | PHPUnit` when using PHPUnit via Composer.

This blog post has all the details (with pictures) to successfully configure IDE for such scenario: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PHPUnit+Installation+via+Composer+in+PhpStorm

**Related usability ticket**: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-18388

**P.S.**
The WI-18388 ticket is already fixed in v8.0