# phpunit run problems in phpstorm, Cannot create phar

Tags: php, yii, phpunit, phpstorm, phar

I am running phpStorm 7.1.3 version on Windows 7 and I have done everything accordingly to install composer and then phpunit. Now I have it in vendors directory. But every time I run my program which is a simple Yii application I get the same error.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with
>   message 'Cannot create phar
>   'C:/wamp/www/myproject/vendor/bin/phpunit', file extension (or
>   combination) not recognised or the directory does not exist' in
>   C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Temp\ide-phpunit.php:177

Please help, I am stuck here already two days and cant get this working, almost changed and reinstalled everything but is not helping.

I didn't use pear, I downloaded everything through the phpStorm. I downloaded composer, and after that through phpStorm composer I downloaded phpUnit 3.7.37.

Here is the screenshot of my settings for composer

[image]

Here is the content of my composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.37"
    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot of my settings for PHPunit
[image]

Comment: 1) What PHPUnit do you use (what installation -- PEAR/Composer/PHAR)? 2) What PHPUnit version it is? 3) Screenshot of "Settings | PHP | PHPUnit" please

Comment: Ok I got everything you asked,,,, if there is anything else please let me know

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On your 2nd screenshot (PHPUnit settings):

- Why did you choose PHAR option if you are using COMPOSER?
- Why did you point to `.../bin/phpunit` (even if you choose 3rd option .. you should point it to a PHAR file then)?

**Therefore:**

- For composer installations you should use 2nd (**"Use custom loader"**) option.
- The edit box -- you should point it to your autoloader script (yes -- composer autoloader script).

Related (similar issue): https://stackoverflow.com/a/17316104/783119

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but now I get a different error

C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\php.exe C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Temp\ide-phpunit.php --no-configuration C:\wamp\www\myproject
Fatal error: Class 'CDbTestCase' not found in C:\wamp\www\myproject\protected\tests\unit\myModelTest.php on line 4


Here is the screenshot of my files [link](http://www.postimg.com/image/149000/files-148345.jpg)

Comment: What is `CDbTestCase`? I guess it's from Yii framework? If so -- make sure that your loader has reference to it .. or init Yii class loader in your bootstrap file used by PHPUnit. It's seems to be just a misconfiguration on your side.

Comment: Thank you very much,,, everything is ok now

Comment: Thanks. I can say, that I've chosen the Phar-option, because most tools and even PHPStorm (in case of phpmd and codesniffer) treats phar files either as executable, or as script.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not using composer, but the 'Path to phpunit.phar' option and still receive this error, just make sure the path you specify ends with a .phar (usually ends with phpunit.phar)  I was seeing this same error but because I had the path pointing to my command-line alias, not the actual .phar file, it gets hung up on the improper extension and bails.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to run phpUnit on zend framework 1.12.9 and had the same problem - solved it by changing path to phpunit.phar to use custom loader. 
Then You have to point it to the generated autoload.php by composer.

In my case that was

```
C:\wamp\www\phpu3\vendor\autoload.php
```

Later, the important thing to do was to point the bootstrap file from tests.

Answer (score 0):

When you download the `phpunit.phar` file using the `wget` command, following the instruction on the getting started manual -
 https://phpunit.de/getting-started/phpunit-4.html 
the "phar" extension is being removed, and PHPSTORM has issues to interrupt this file. I've changed the extension:

```
mv phpunit phpunit.phar
```

make sure you update the path to `phpunit.phar` file in the IDE setting accordingly